# search icon not showing in toolbar

Tags: java, android, searchview

I have several searchviews in my app, I want to implement it in another fragment and I copy and paste everything like it is in the other fragments where it is working, obviously changing variables and so, for it to not cause conflict or something and my app runs ok, the toolbar is showing but not my searchview, once I change from tab to tab and return to this fragment now it shows, and I don't know why, please any help would be great

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".ManageFragments.MainActivity">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:title="@string/action_search"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

**Search_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/GrayBackground"
    tools:context=".HomeFragments.SearchFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="clip_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment**

```
  final MenuItem mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) mSearchMenuItem.getActionView();
        //final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setQueryHint(getText(R.string.search));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit( String query)
            {
                final GifTextView loading = (GifTextView)FeedsFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loadingSearch);
                final TextView loadingText = (TextView)FeedsFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loadingTextSearch);
                final ImageView loadingBackground = (ImageView)FeedsFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgGrayBackgroundSearch);
                loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loadingText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loadingBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //Toast.makeText(SearchFragment.this.getActivity(), R.string.buscado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                searchView.setQuery("", false);
                searchView.setIconified(true);
                new PlifRequestBase(getActivity()){
                    @Override
                    public JsonObject onHttpOk(JsonObject response) throws JSONException
                    {
                        JsonObject data, pagination_details = null, businesses, cover_premium, cv, iurl;
                        JsonArray premiums, basics;
                        if (response.get("pagination") == null)
                        {
                            data =  response;
                        }else {
                            pagination_details = response.get("pagination").getAsJsonObject();
                            data = response.get("data").getAsJsonObject();

                            businesses = data.get("businesses").getAsJsonObject();
                            premiums = businesses.get("premiums").getAsJsonArray();
                            basics = businesses.get("basics").getAsJsonArray();

                            gson = new Gson();
                            arrayBusiness = new ArrayList<Business>();
                            arrayBasics= new ArrayList<Business>();

                            arrayBusiness = gson.fromJson(premiums, BUSINESS_TYPE);
                            arrayBasics=gson.fromJson(basics, BUSINESS_TYPE);
                            Log.d("size", String.valueOf(arrayBusiness.size()));
                            //Log.d("", String.valueOf(images_premiums));
                            if (getActivity() == null)
                                return response;
                            FeedsFragment.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) FeedsFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.high_recycler_view);
                                    RecyclerView recyclerbasics=(RecyclerView) FeedsFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lower_recycler_view);

                                    SearchHorizontalAdapter adapter = new SearchHorizontalAdapter(getActivity(), arrayBusiness, R.layout.search_high_layout);
                                    SearchVerticalAdapter adapterbasics=new SearchVerticalAdapter(getActivity(),arrayBasics,R.layout.search_low_layout);

                                    recyclerbasics.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                                    recycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

                                    mLowerLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(FeedsFragment.this.getActivity(),2);
                                    recyclerbasics.setLayoutManager(mLowerLayoutManager);
                                    recyclerbasics.setAdapter(adapterbasics);

                                    mLayoutManagera = new LinearLayoutManager(FeedsFragment.this.getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                                    recycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManagera);
                                    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

                                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayBusiness.size(); i++)
                                    {
                                        Log.d("Imprime", arrayBusiness.get(i).getName());
                                    }
                                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayBasics.size(); i++)
                                    {
                                        Log.d("Imprime", arrayBasics.get(i).getName());
                                    }


                                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    loadingText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    loadingBackground.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        if (pagination_details.isJsonNull()){
                            Log.d("Paginacion", pagination_details.toString());
                        }

                        return data;

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onHttpCreate(JsonObject response) throws JSONException
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onHttpUnprocessableEntity(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {
                        this.cancel(true);
                        final String error = response.get("errors").toString();
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }.execute("businesses/search", "GET", "q", "\'"+query.replaceAll(" ","&").trim()+"\'");

                return true;

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                textView.setText(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });

        View searchPlate = (View) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
        searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.textfield_custom);

        //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {


            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfm3K.jpg this is where I'm having problems, it is not showing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zCiB.jpg and here I moved from tab to tab and return and now it is showing